# dataTable row into hyperlink error

Tags: jquery, datatable, href

I'm new to deal with dataTable. I tried to convert the row into `href` using below code:

```
"fnRowCallback": function( row, data ) {
    $('tr', row).html('<a href="userDet/' + data[3] + '"><td>' +data[0]+ '</td><td>' +data[1]+ '</td><td>' +data[2]+ '</td></a>');
    return row;
},
```

which is not working, but while convert `href` to single column. It's working fine.

```
"fnRowCallback": function( row, data ) {
    $('td:eq(1)', row).html('<a href="userDet/' + data[3] + '"><td>' +data[0]+ '</td></a>');
    return row;
},
```

what i'm doing wrong?

**Edit**

My `html` is:

```
            <table id="myTable" class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Door No</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th style="display: none;">Account ID</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                </tbody>
            </table>
```

my `Jquery` is:

```
    var oTable = jQuery('#myTable').dataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "pageLength": 6,
    "ajax": '/userDetails?query='+query+'',
    "type":'get',
    "fnRowCallback": function( row, data ) {
                $('td:eq(1)', row).on('click',function(){
                  window.location = 'userDet/' + data[3] ;
                });
            },

    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "targets": [ 3 ],
            "visible": false,
            "searchable": true
        }
    ]        

    });
```

Comment: You need to follow the table HTML structure .. table, tbody, tr, td.... If this structure breaks then your CSS will break  and dataTables features might break too..

Comment: thanks.. but i directly importing into the `tbody`. no problem with the dataTable. The only problem is convert them into `ahref` @Reddy

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow the table HTML structure.. *table, tbody, tr, td*.... If this structure breaks then your CSS will break and DataTables features might break too..

Your approach will break the table structure as you are attempting to put a `a` tag directly under `tr`. `tr` should always have `td` as it's child.

***Solution:*** Use `data-*` attribute to store the navigation URL in the `tr` tag and on click of this `tr`  load the page you want just like a anchor tag click..

***Here is sample:***

```
"fnRowCallback": function( row, data ) {
    $('tr', row).attr('data-navigate-url','userDet/' + data[3]);
    return row;
},
```

This will set the attributes on your TR tags..

Add click event handler to these `tr` tags

```
$("#yourTable").on('click','tr',function(){
    window.location = $(this).data('navigate-url');
});
```

Comment: Excuse me for the code formatting issue.. I am on mobile app and I have no option for code formatting.. If anybody can format this I'll be glad.. Thanks

Comment: i got `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined`

Comment: @m2j I don't think that might be anything related to the above code. Can you check and confirm?

Comment: thank you so much @Reddy. the click event handler saves my time. but my window open with `/undefined`. i found the way to make it with your help